# Material UI custom portable input component

Tags: material-ui

I have a question regarding MUI (http://mui.com), maybe someone can guide me to the correct solution. I want to create a custom input that is portable, which means it can ideally be used standalone or in conjunction with `TextField`, which is great to use and recreating it for custom components seems to be pretty heavy overhead.

I.e. i want to create a custom input component for monetary data. It should be an input with an adornment and handling some parsing/transforming of the value when typing etc. The actual implementation is not important, as my question is how do i make it portable. To use startAdornment etc. i must use one of the `Input|OutlinedInput|FilledInput` components, making it unusable with TextField as the inputProps.inputComponent only applies to innermost component so specifying it will result in something like `<OutlinedInput><OutlinedInput /></OutlinedInput>`, which is syntactically incorrect and breaks some styling. And also `variant` would not work, as i already used one concrete Input component.

If i omit MUIs input completely, to use it later as `inputComponent` prop for MUIs `Input`-variants, i lose the ability to use `startAdornment` etc., which will result in weird results or at least me being forced to recreate those adornment stylings etc.

Any ideas how to achieve portability? It seems `TextField` component is not designed for such a case, and i might be left with creating some kind of `CustomComponentTextField` myself.